# Format accessibility label for price

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiaccessibility

I use `NSNumberFormatter` to format price for voice over. I found that it works fine when no thousands separator used and for certain list of currencies such as US$, €, £, however it doesn't seem to work for any other currencies, e.g. CA$ is pronounced as C-A-Dollar...  What's the right way to configure `NSNumberFormatter` to get a decent output suitable for voice over?

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = NO;
formatter.currencyCode = @"NOK";

view.accessibilityLabel = [formatter stringFromNumber:@100];
```

As Carl mentioned below, `.CurrencyPluralStyle` can be used. It formats currency based on locale and ignores all other settings even `usesGroupingSeparator`. With some manual work it can be a suitable alternative!

Example below:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currencyPlural
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = false // being entirely ignored :/
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_CA")

let str = formatter.string(from: 1000.50)!

print("\(str)")
```

Produces:

> 1,000.50 Canadian dollars

Comment: you want it to say as canadian dollar instead of C-A $ ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri yes

Comment: if you set currency code to CAD, it only shows the $100, but not as CA$100. How did you get the CA part ?

Comment: Also you can format the accessibility label as per you r requiremetns. Check the locale based on it, change the accessibility label. If the locale is CAD, then you can add Canadian string to the accessibility label and then append the $100 to the string.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri display name for currency depends on locale. US$ appears as $ when using US locale, and as US$ when using european locale.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri you suggest that I do manual localization for hundred currencies? No thanks.

Comment: why for all currencies? Do it for the one that is not pronouncing as you like.

Comment: You may be able to set the currencyGroupingSeparator to an empty string to avoid that being used in the result.  Though I haven't tried; if it ignores useGroupingSeparator it may ignore that too.

Comment: @CarlLindberg it ignores that too. But anyway I can find our grouping separator from locale and replace it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyPluralStyle` meet your needs?  That is iOS9 and later only, though.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13973938)

Comment: @BeauNouvelle -- NSNumberFormatterCurrencyPluralStyle is the way to configure an NSNumberFormatter to generate the full name of the currency, which seemed to be the question.  It generates the number in a slightly different fashion than the original version, so it wasn't clear if that still met the original needs (or if they needed to support iOS8), but it is a solution to the general question on iOS9 and later.  The different style would be the only change to the example code.